# Replace wrapping struct with a type declaration in Go

Tags: initialization, go, type-conversion

I want to extend the `regexp` from the Go standard library to be able to define my own methods. I use the following struct:

```
type RichRegexp struct {
    *regexp.Regexp
}
```

As you can see, this struct contains nothing but the wrapped `regexp.Regexp`. So I wonder whether I could replace this with a simple type declaration like this:

```
type RichRegexp regexp.Regexp
```

But how should I write the following func then?

```
func Compile(expression string) (*RichRegexp, error) {
    regex, err := regexp.Compile(expression)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &RichRegexp{regex}, nil // How to do this?
}
```

I tried to convert `regexp.Regexp` to my `RichRegexp` but it didn't compile. What is the general pattern to return a custom type which wraps a underlying type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package main

import (
        "regexp"
)

type RichRegexp regexp.Regexp

func Compile(expression string) (*RichRegexp, error) {
        regex, err := regexp.Compile(expression)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        return (*RichRegexp)(regex), nil
}

func main() {
    Compile("foo")
}
```

Also here: http://play.golang.org/p/cgpi8z2CfF

Answer (score 5):

You can use a conversion, but in this case it is necessary, that your type definition is not  a pointer:

```
type MyRegexp *regexp.Regexp // Doesn't work
```

This is backed by [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> The receiver type must be of the form T or *T where T is a type name.
>   The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; **it must not be
>   a pointer or interface type** and it must be declared in the same
>   package as the method. The method is said to be bound to the base type
>   and the method name is visible only within selectors for that type.

However, you can do this:

```
type MyRegexp regexp.Regexp
```

As you're handling values now, you can do the following:

```
x := regexp.MustCompile(".*")
y := MyRegexp(*x)
```

And you have your own regexp type.

Full code at play: http://play.golang.org/p/OWNdA2FinN

As a general pattern, I would would say:

- If it's unlikely to change and you don't need to store arbitrary values, use 
  a type conversion.
- If you need to store values along with your embedded type, use a `struct`.
- If your code is likely to change and needs to support large varieties of things,
  define an interface and don't use embedding / type conversion.

Comment: `MyRegexp(*x)` doesn't work in my case, since I have to return a pointer. If I try `y := &MyRegexp(*x)` I get the error `cannot take the address of MyRegexp(*x)` http://play.golang.org/p/HbVoAVM1RY .

Comment: If you want a pointer, simply convert it to a pointer of `MyRegexp` like so: `(*MyRegexp)(x)`. Note that there is no requirement for the dereferenciation of `x` anymore, as we're now dealing with pointers. See [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) for additional informations :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. `(*MyRegexp)(x)` is what 'jnml' suggested too.